# Get nested data from local JSON file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Now that I have the `NSDictionary` object `JSONDictionary`, how do I **get the nested data inside** of it?

```
    NSString *JSONFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sAPI" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:JSONFilePath];
    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", JSONDictionary);
```

`sAPI.json` snippet:

```
{
    "ss": [{
               "name": "bl",
               },
               "ls": [{
                           "name": "ML",
                           "abbreviation": "ml",
                           "id": 10,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked me to do this in a comment on a different answer, I'll answer it here. To get the `name` value of one of the leagues, follow this

```
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil]; //root object
NSArray *sports = JSONDictionary[@"sports"]; //array containing all sports (baseball, football, etc.)
NSDictionary *baseball = sports[0]; //dictionary containing info about baseball
NSArray *baseballLeagues = baseball[@"leagues"]; //array containing all leagues for baseball
NSDictionary *MLB = baseballLeagues[0]; //dictionary for only the MLB league
NSString *MLBName = MLB[@"name"]; //the full name of the MLB
```

This example only works for the MLB, but can easily be changed by finding the index of the other league or sport you want to use.

Note that the square brackets used in this answer are shorthand for the following methods

```
dictionary[@"key"]; -short for-> [dictionary objectForKey:@"key"];
array[0]; -short for-> [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: This is awesome, perfect!!! Thank you so much for the answer and how you explain it so well.  Seriously, you rock!